# Factoring out where clauses

Tags: sql, refactoring, db2, where-clause

I have some SQL queries in DB2 stored procs with very complicated where clauses which are hard to read, maintain, and impossible to share across select statements without copy&pasting. I used to write dynamic SQL and concatenated the parts of the where clause separately which at least made the logic clearer. **Is there a way to do this without dynamic SQL?** I'm thinking about user defined functions but they are too heavyweight and possibly too slow for this. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know DB2.  Does it support views?  I think "factoring out where clauses" might be a very good explanation of what purpose views serve.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the clauses can be determined before the query (i.e.: based on parameters passed to the stored procedure), the result of that clause can be stored in a variable and then just use the variable in the query. For sharing with other stored procedures, you could extract that to a separate stored procedure.

Any clauses that are not based on parameters of the stored procedure could be extracted to a view. All stored procedures could then query the view with the actual parameters. Note that this could be slower than a single SQL statement, particularly if you could narrow down significantly the rows in tables prior to joins.

Other than that, I believe you are stuck with using either dynamic SQL or copy/pasting.